# Function to find the Dot product

Tags: c++, function, dynamic-memory-allocation, dot-product

I'm trying to fill up two arrays and then use a function to find the dot product. Sometimes it will work and sometimes it won't. I'm not sure if it is how I am filling up the arrays, or if it how I'm working on the function. Also, if I set the size to 6 and input 1,2,3,4,5,6 the first array will be filled with 1,2,3,4,1,2... it resets after 4. The second array is properly filled.
 I don't know if someone can give me a hand on this.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int dotProduct(int* array1, int*array2, int size);

int main() {

    int  size = 0;

    int *array_one = new int[size]{};
    int *array_two = new int[size]{};

    cout << "Please enter array size:" << "\n";
    cin >> size;

    while (size <= 0) { // First while loop, checking array size

        cout << "Please enter array size:" << "\n";
        cin >> size;
    }                 //end of first while loop

    cout << "========= Begin Entering Array Elements =========" 
         << "\n";
    cout << "Array 1: "<< "\n";

    for (int i = 0; i<size; i++){ // Filling up first array, first for 
        loop
            cout << "Enter element number "<< i+1 << ": " ;
        cin >> array_one[i];
    }                               // end or first for loop

    cout <<"=================================================" << 
        "\n";
    cout << "Array 2:" << "\n";

    for (int i = 0; i<size; i++){ // Filling up first array, first for 
        loop
            cout << "Enter element number "<< i+1 << ": " ;
        cin >> array_two[i];
    }

    cout << "The dot product is: " << 
        dotProduct(array_one,array_two,size);
}

int dotProduct(int *arrayUno, int *arrayDos, int size){

    int total = 0;

    for (int i =0; i <= size ; i++ ){
        total = total + (*arrayUno)*(*arrayDos);
        arrayUno++;
        arrayDos++;
    }

    return total;
}
```

Comment: Now is probably a very good time [to learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: That was a really good read! Thanks for sharing it!

Answer (score 1):

```
int  size = 0;

int *array_one = new int[size]{};
int *array_two = new int[size]{};

cout << "Please enter array size:" << "\n";
cin >> size;

while (size <= 0) { // First while loop, checking array size

    cout << "Please enter array size:" << "\n";
    cin >> size;
}                 //end of first while loop
```

You allocate the arrays before you get the size. You have to get the size first. Change this code to:

```
int size = 0;

cout << "Please enter array size:" << "\n";
cin >> size;

int *array_one = new int[size]{};
int *array_two = new int[size]{};
```

Comment: You should add the `while` loop to your answer.

Comment: Oh god, I missed that part. Thanks.

Comment: My first mistake was that in the function I didn't initialize total. when I made total = 0;  I stopped having errors. now the arrays are in the wrong positions... I didn't even catch that after hours of looking at the problem. I appreciate the help! I really do. I need to learn how to debug  my small codes.

Comment: It was a small issue, I have been in the same situation many times. If you think this answer helped, feel free to accept it as the answer to your question! <3